# Grammar of 高くても安くても

Tags: grammar

> 宿代が高くても安くても金はない - "There is no money to pay for lodging, high or low."

I've seen ーくても being used to mean "Even if", くても but what about "くても+くても"? Is there a different meaning when using this composition?

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say it has a different meaning, but it certainly would come out being phrased differently in English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ても still means "even if" in this context. As @Angelos commented, it's the matter of English translation.

The basic idea of AてもB is that it shows **contrastive** relationship between A and B. In other words, AてもB means "B is true regardless A."

Besides "even if," there are many ways to render this idea in English. You can use "no matter how/what..." or "regardless of..." etc.

> 宿代が高くても安くても金はない
>
> It doesn't matter if hotel charges are expensive or cheap, I don't have money.

Answer (score 2):

It's still "even if". Literally, 高くても安くても means "even if (the price is) high or even if (the price is) low". But you can translate this simply like "regardless of its price", "whatever the price is", "no matter how cheap it is", etc.